# Adding Root Node in the Output

Tags: xslt-2.0

My output looks like

```xml
<TransactionLog TID="1400" SeqNo="3337446" SQLTransaction="Insert into TankerLoads Values(141221,53,299,18,1,426148,6,'Nov 19 2007 12:00AM','Dec 30 1899 12:59PM',3.00,20682,0,'Zevo','Nov 19 2007 12:00AM',0)" />
```

where I need to add `<root>` node so that it will look like below

```xml
<root>
  <TransactionLog TID="1400" SeqNo="3337446" SQLTransaction="Insert into TankerLoads Values(141221,53,299,18,1,426148,6,'Nov 19 2007 12:00AM','Dec 30 1899 12:59PM',3.00,20682,0,'Zevo','Nov 19 2007 12:00AM',0)" />
</root>
```

I combined all the records by using below code and now I need to add root node and I need to diplay this with OUTPUT METHOD AS TEXT. Please help me.

```xml
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: don't see any code. remember to use the "code foramtting" in the form

Answer (score 0):

**You can capture the output of your transformation in a variable and apply to the contents of the variable a transformation similar to this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vResult1">
   <TransactionLog TID="1400"
     SeqNo="3337446"
     SQLTransaction="Insert into TankerLoads Values(141221,53,299,18,1,426148,6,'Nov 19 2007 12:00AM','Dec 30 1899 12:59PM',3.00,20682,0,'Zevo','Nov 19 2007 12:00AM',0)" />
</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="pass2">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="pass2"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$vResult1/*" mode="pass2"/>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is performed on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<root>
   <TransactionLog TID="1400" SeqNo="3337446"
                   SQLTransaction="Insert into TankerLoads Values(141221,53,299,18,1,426148,6,'Nov 19 2007 12:00AM','Dec 30 1899 12:59PM',3.00,20682,0,'Zevo','Nov 19 2007 12:00AM',0)"/>
</root>
```

**Alternatively, and much better, modify your existing transformation to something like this:**

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>
```

**Or if your transformation already has a template matching `/`:**

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
   <!-- Put the body of your current template here -->
  </root>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for all your response but I am not able to get the root node and I think I need to give my full requirement

Comment: But I have 100 records <TransactionLog TID="1400" SeqNo="3337446" SQLTransaction="Insert into TankerLoads Values(141221,53,299,18,1,426148,6,'Nov 19 2007 12:00AM','Dec 30 1899 12:59PM',3.00,20682,0,'Zevo','Nov 19 2007 12:00AM',0)"/> like this how I can achive because I am combining all these 100 records in a one row..please help me

Comment: I want to mention one more thing my output mode = text when I apply <xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </root>
 </xsl:template> its working for xml output but when I keep output as text it is not working..please help me

Comment: @Akhil: You shouldn't be using `<xsl:output method="text"/>` -- because the wanted result is an XML document! Please, edit the question and specify any important for its understanding information.